# JavaFX: Focusing textfield programmatically

Tags: events, focus, javafx-2, textfield

I wrote an application with JavaFX which will only be usable with keyboard's arrows.
So I prevented MouseEvent on Scene's stage, and I "listen" to KeyEvents.
I also switched off focusability of all nodes :

```
for(Node n : children) {
     n.setFocusTraversable(false);
```

Now I have some textfields, checkboxes, and buttons.
I would like to change the state of my input controls (textfield, checkbox,..) programatically: for example I would like to enter the textfield to edit the content programatically.
So my question is: how to enter in a non-focus-traversable textfield?
Because textfield.requestFocus(); doesn't work anymore since I set false to focustraversable property of my textfield.

Thanks

Comment: If you want to programmatically set the value of a textfield, you could simply use `setText`? If I have misunderstood your question, could you please rephrase what the problem is, what you have tried, and what doesn't work?

Comment: I edited my question and added that I did

Comment: @PacDroid you said requestFocus() is working in the comment of my answer below. Also I edited my answer with more details as per your comment. You need to clarify this confusion.

Comment: Yes, it's ok by requesting focus in a separate thread, thank you :)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

By the following code:

```
n.setFocusTraversable(false);
```

...the node is made non-focus-traversable instead of non-focusable. It can still be focused for example by mouse or programmatically. Since you prevented mouse events, here the other option:

```
Platform.runLater(() -> textfield.requestFocus());

Scene scene = new Scene(root);
```

**EDIT: as per comment,**
The Javadoc of `requestFocus` states:

> ... To be eligible to receive the focus, the node must be part of a scene,
> it and all of its ancestors must be visible, and it must not be
> disabled. ...

So this method should be called after construction of scene graph as follow:

```
Scene scene = new Scene(root);
textfield.requestFocus();
```

However, Platform.runLater in the above will run at the end, after the main method `start()`, which ensures the call of requestFocus will be after scene graph cosntruction.

There maybe other reasons depending on the requestFocus implementation code.

Comment: Ok, I tested it worked.
Why doesn't it work with a simple textfield.requestFocus(); at the end of my parent-Pane construction?

Comment: Thank you it's clearer now for me :)
I think that I will create my own controls that can only be focused by a method that change their visual states.
Thank you

Comment: What will be the component who get's the focus per default? Is it the first created component, like a Button?

Answer (score 2):

set the .requestFocus(); on initialize method to fire on .fxml file loading controller

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
/* the field defined on .fxml document  
@FXML
private TextField txtYear;
*/
txtYear.requestFocus();
}
```

Comment: In my case that does not work in the `public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb)`. I had to set it after the scene was created and set to a stage.

Comment: This does not work