# BorderPane does not set the appropriate order of focus for TextFields

Tags: java, javafx, focus, fxml, scenebuilder

I have created the following scene with the help of Scene Builder:

- I set up a BorderPane
- In the *insert TOP* area I have placed a MenuBar
- In the *insert CENTER* I have placed some TextFields
- In the *insert BOTTOM* area I have placed a Button

Upon opening my application, the **focus** is given to the Button that was placed in the *insert BOTTOM* section.

[This is an image depicting this specific scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QaOO.png)

What can I do to set the focus to the first TextField in the *insert CENTER* section?

I have tried the following in order to solve this issue:

1. I made sure that the Hierarchy order was correct (i.e. the center
   node comes before the bottom node).
2. I tried using `.requestFocus()` within my `initialize()` declaration but that did not work since `initialize()` occurs before loading the controller as described in [JavaFx:What if I want to do something after initialize(),before the scene show,how can I achieve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30929310/javafxwhat-if-i-want-to-do-something-after-initialize-before-the-scene-show-h).
3. Another option I looked into was @Uluk Biy's answer in this question: [JavaFX: Focusing textfield programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20049452/javafx-focusing-textfield-programmatically). However, in my application I have two controllers (main_controller.java and sample_app_controller). The main_controller.java is responsible for launching the application, meaning that it has the `public static void main(String[] args) {launch(args));}` and `public void start(Stage primaryStage)` functions through which my application runs. sample_app_controller is responsible of handling anything that happens in the second screen (the one I provided in this post). I understand that I can place the code provided by @Uluk Biy in my `public void start(Stage primaryStage` function. However, at that point I am in a different screen which is controlled by a different java file, so I can't really apply that solution.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15238928/javafx-how-to-change-the-focus-traversal-policy